# How to display image having fixed Uri in Image View in android

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-imageview

I want to display an Image and buttons below it in a LinearLayout. For the image, I am using an ImageView and the 2 buttons are part of a nested LinearLayout.

You might be thinking, that this is already available on the Net. Why is this guy wasting our time? What is different in this?

The difference is that the Uri of the Image to be displayed is static. Most of the code examples I have seen on the Net use an Image Picker to  determine the Uri of the Image. But due to some constraints, I can't use an Image Picker but can ensure that the Image to be displayed has the same fixed string as Uri always.

So, here is what I tried:

## activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:id="@+id/image_view"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Start"
        android:id="@+id/start_btn" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Stop"
        android:id="@+id/stop_btn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String picturePath = "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1.jpg";

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
// Some auto-generated methods here.
```

}

---

As you can see, the image I am trying to load is at "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1.jpg". But, this app keeps crashing as soon as it is launched.
So, please guide me on how to fix this. And I am a newbie to Android Programming, please pardon me if my attempts at coding this app seem pathetic.

And goes without saying, Thanks in Advance :)

---

EDIT:
     As requested by @Jonty800, here's the output of Logcat with the log level set to "Debug":

```
07-12 02:07:07.937  23773-23773/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
07-12 02:07:08.037  23773-23773/com.example.debayan.usingimageview D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 108K, 36% free 14480K/22584K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
07-12 02:07:08.137  23773-23773/com.example.debayan.usingimageview I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 66.234MB for 52515856-byte allocation
07-12 02:07:08.517  23773-23773/com.example.debayan.usingimageview D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-12 02:07:08.517  23773-23773/com.example.debayan.usingimageview W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417bfd58)
07-12 02:07:08.527  23773-23773/com.example.debayan.usingimageview E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.debayan.usingimageview, PID: 23773
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.debayan.usingimageview/com.example.debayan.usingimageview.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:806)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.debayan.usingimageview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:806)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May we have a look at the crash report? Remember that you must provide permissions to access the SD Card in your Manifest.xml file, this could be the cause.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Edit:

Perhaps try something like this:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/DCIM/Camera/1.jpg";

File imgFile = new File(path);
if(imgFile.exists())
{
   Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
   ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
  imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}else{
   System.out.println("Image does not exist");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I already have this line in the manifest file and still the app crashes.

Comment: And I have edited the question and added Logcat's output. Hope I have given all the info you requested.

Comment: Your setContentView appears to be in the wrong place.  Try your code with  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); directly below line  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: If I do that, the app does not crash but it does not load the image too. Instead, I get a blank ImageView with two buttons underneath it. (which is to be expected I guess as I am setting the ContentView and not doing anything with the ImageView before that).

Comment: Are you sure that your image path is correct? Perhaps try something like this:

String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/DCIM/Camera/1.jpg";

File imgFile = new File(path);
if(imgFile.exists())
{
   Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
   ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
  imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
}else{ 
   System.out.println("Image does not exist");
}

Comment: no luck with that one either. But I have confirmed one thing. The code does enter the 'if' block, i.e, the Image does exist. But the app still keeps crashing.

Comment: That's rather strange then, using  BitmapFactory.decodeFile is a typical way of managing this. Perhaps try with another image to check that it's not the file that is the issue?

Comment: no, that does not seem to be the issue. I  tried with another image's Uri and same error. :(

Comment: Aaaah,I get it finally. The code sample you gave me worked properly, but since my image was 3120x4208, it exceeded the 4096x4096 limit on the Bitmap size (and hence, I got the error "Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (3120x4208, max=4096x4096)". I tried it with a smaller image and it worked like a charm. :D  @Jonty800 , do you have any suggestions as to what to do for larger images?

Comment: Sure, for my apps I use a PHP script to reduce the size of the image. Unfortunately you'll need a webserver for this, but check out https://code.google.com/p/timthumb/. Otherwise, you should consider shrinking the image before displaying. The android guidelines provides some information for this: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html